# Search only last records grouping by columns

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

I would like to bring only the latest information grouping by vehicles (description) according to travel (id_travel_fk)

I have the following query

```
const vehiclesStates = await this.pg.reg_vehicles_states
    .createQueryBuilder("rvs")
    .select([
      "rvs.registration_date", "rvs.finish_date", "rvs.duration",
      "rv.description", "rv.external_id", "rv.license_plate",
      "tvt.type",
      "rt.registration_date", "rt.external_id", "rt.num_doc", "rt.load_label", "rt.description",
      "rd.name", "rd.external_id",
      "rlo.name", "rlo.address", "rlo.number", "rlo.district", "rlo.cep", "rlo.complement",
      "rlo.latitude", "rlo.longitude", "rlo.description", "rlo.external_id",
      "rld.name", "rld.address", "rld.number", "rld.district", "rld.cep", "rld.complement",
      "rld.latitude", "rld.longitude", "rld.description"," rld.external_id",
      "tvst.type"
    ])
    .leftJoin("rvs.travel", "rt")
    .innerJoin("rvs.vehicle", "rv")
    .innerJoin("rv.type", "tvt")
    .leftJoin("rt.driver", "rd")
    .leftJoin("rt.destination", "rld")
    .leftJoin("rt.origin", "rlo")
    .innerJoin("rvs.type", "tvst")
    .getMany();
```

With the following [Query return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdyzP.png) bringing all the bank records ..

The intention would be to bring only the first 4 records, as highlighted in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ5VY.png).
Grouping the data by vehicles (description) and bringing only the last records referenced to the column (id_travel_fk)

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Try using `.take(4)` before `.getMany()`

Comment: @firatozcevahir It would not necessarily be the first 4 always, it would only be in that case. The amount you would like to bring can be dynamic.

I was able to solve the problem, using other query's to search for the link id that I would like (Last) using MAX and filtering only by these next.

I appreciate the help = D